# Style Individual Lists in Wordpress

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out how to style this correctly. I am trying to add a FontAwesome icon as a list bullet style to a specific text widget in Wordpress. Here is the CSS:

```
.covenant li {
counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
margin: 0.25rem;
}

.covenant li:before {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
content: '\f005';
margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
}
```

and here is the HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="covenant">Text</li>
<li class="covenant">Text</li>
<li class="covenant">Text</li>
<li class="covenant">Text</li>
</ul>
```

Can't figure out what I'm missing!

Comment: Although you are using wordpress, the above question appears to be purely CSS & HTML related.

Comment: I believe this: `.covenant li:before` should be `li.covenant:before` if you are targeting the `li` elements that have the `covenant` class applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.covenant {
    counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
    margin: 0.25rem;
}

.covenant:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f005';
    margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting the HTML incorrectly in your CSS, it needs to be:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li.covenant {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}

li.covenant:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f005';
  margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
}
```

.covenant is the class assigned to the li that you are trying to target.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c2ohp3y2/

Comment: Thanks! This works great, except now it is showing the icon next to the normal rounded bullet point.

Comment: If you look at the link provided I have sorted that problem out for you too. All you need is: **`ul { list-style: none; }`**

Comment: I added **`ul .covenant {list-style: none !important;}`** and it's perfect now. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: No worries. You shouldn't need to add !important but if it works thats fine, can you accept my answer please?